# Split String by XML tags in Java

Tags: java, xml, regex, xml-parsing

I want to write a method in Java that splits a String by XML tags like follows:

```
"Lorem ipsum <b>dolor</b> sit amet consetetur <b>diam</b> nonumy."
```

Should return the Array:

```
["Lorem ipsum ", "<b>dolor</b>", " sit amet consetetur ", "<b>diam</b>", " nonumy."]
```

This should work for every XML tag, also self closing tags like `<element />`.

Is there a library that does something similar in a simple way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using lookaround in your split should do the trick:

```
String splits[] = input.split("\\s+(?=<b>)|(?<=</b>)\\s+");
```

Example:

```
String input = "Lorem ipsum <b>dolor</b> sit amet consetetur <b>diam</b> nonumy.";
for(String s : input.split("\\s+(?=<b>)|(?<=</b>)\\s+")){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

If you want to keep the space intact in your spitted array, then remove the `\\s+` from the regex.

Comment: Great! As a follow-up question: do you know a generic regexp for every XML tag I can use? I can not know which tags will come. The regexp should also match self closing tags like `<element/>` and with attributes too.

Comment: Variable tags will not work as lookbehind(`<=...`) only supports a fixed length.

Comment: I have solved that with an interval `(?=<mynamespace:.*?>)|(?<=</mynamespace:.{1,20}>)`.

Comment: Ok, and with self closing tags the regex look as follows: `((?=<mynamespace:.*?>)|(?<=</mynamespace:.{1,20}>))|((?=<mynamespace:.*?)|(?<=/>))`.